# How to rest a DropDownList after Post

Tags: c#

Trying to rest my DropDownList in my c# Web app when a user clicks the submit button. How can I reset it to the default when it does a postback? Can someone give me an example?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(IsPostBack)
 {
   dropdownlist.DataSource=null;
   dropdownlist.DataBind();

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
DropDownList.ClearSelection();
```